# how to check which dynamically button is touched

Tags: javascript, angular6

I have created dynamic buttons in angular 6. how can i find out which button is touched in typescript.

```
assigndynamicfields() {

    setTimeout(() => {

      this.getRecord();

      //call service and assign dynamic config data
      this.fieldsData.push({
        name: "save",
        type: "button",
        label: "Save"
      },
        {
          name: "delete",
          type: "button",
          label: "Delete"
        }
      )
        ;
      this.regConfig = this.fieldsData;
      this.form = DynamicFormComponent;

    }, 500)
  }
```

Comment: The button was inside a form?

Comment: Yes it is. I am looping through all fields... input fields show touched but buttons dont. Object.keys(this.formGrp.controls).forEach(field => {
      if (field==="delete") { 
      const control = this.formGrp.get(field);
      var t = control.touched; 
      console.log(field + " : " + t); 
      }
    });

Comment: i will loop all the fields and check what button is clicked. then run function based on the button clicked. ie if its delete then run delete function etc.

Comment: 6: button.mat-raised-button.mat-primary                                      
7: button.mat-raised-button.mat-primary.cdk-focused.cdk-touch-focused

# 7 is delete button, i see the .cdk-focused.cdk-touch-focused when button is clicked... how can i use this info to determine which button is clicked.... formgroup.controls.touched is not working for buttons... your help is much appreciated. THX